# What is the exact usage of Interrupts in java?

Tags: java, concurrency, interrupt

I am new to Java concurrecny and I am reading this at the moment: [Java Tutorial-Interrupts](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html) But I can't really understand where and why I should use an Interrupt. Can someone give me an example (code) so I better understand it? thx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=java+thread+interrupt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interrupts are used when you want to (cough) interrupt the thread -- typically meaning stop it from operating.  `Thread.stop()` has been deprecated because of various issues so `Thread.interrupt()` is the way that you tell the thread that it should cease running -- it should cleanup what it is doing and quit.  In reality, the programmer can use the interrupt signal on a thread in any way that they want.

Some examples:

- Your thread might be sleeping for a minute and then spidering a web-page.  You want it to stop this behavior.
- Maybe you have a thread which is consuming from a queue of jobs and you want to tell it that no more jobs are coming its way.
- Maybe you have a number of background threads that you want to interrupt because the process is shutting down and you want to do so cleanly.

There are certainly many ways to accomplish the above signaling but interrupt can be used.

One of the more powerful ways that `Thread.interrupt()` affects a running thread is by throwing `InterruptedException` from a couple different methods including `Thread.sleep()`, `Object.wait()`, and others.

```
try {
   Thread.sleep(1000);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
   // i've been interrupted
   // catching InterruptedException clears the interrupt status on the thread
   // so a good pattern is to re-interrupt the thread
   Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
   // but maybe we want to just kill the thread
   return;
}
```

Also, often in a thread we are looping doing some task and so we check for interrupt status:

```
while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
    // keep doing our task until we are interrupted
}
```

Comment: `Thread.currentThread().interrupt()` does not "clear the interrupt status". On the contrary, it re-sets the status since the mechanism which threw the `InterruptedException` cleared it.

Comment: Sorry, my comment was unclear.  I've reworded it.  Thanks @Tim.

Answer (score 1):

With multi-threading, the idea is that you have some work that you divide up among several threads.  The classic example would be to have a thread that does a background calculation or a background action such as a server query that will take a fair amount of time without doing that action in the main thread that handles the user interface.

By offloading those actions that might take a noticeable amount of time, you can prevent the user interface from seeming to get stuck.  An example of this would be when you start an action in a displayed dialog, go to another window then return to the displayed dialog and the dialog does not update itself when you click on it.

Sometimes the background activity needs to be stopped.  In that case you would use the Thread.interrupt() method to request that the thread stop itself.

An example might be if you have a client that is getting status information from a server once a second.  The background thread handles the communication to the server and getting the data.  The user interface thread takes the data and updates the display.  Then the user presses a Stop or Cancel button on the display.  The user interface thread then does an interrupt on the background thread so that it will stop requesting the status information from the server.

Answer (score 0):

In concurrent programming, many programmers arrive at the conclusion that they need to stop a thread. They decide it would be a good idea to have some sort of `boolean` flag to tell indicate to the thread that it should stop. The interrupt flag is that boolean mechanism provided through the Java standard library.

For example:

```
class LongIterativeTask implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        while (!thread.isInterrupted()) { //while not interrupted
            //do an iteration of a long task
        }
    }
 }

class LongSequentialTask implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        //do some work
        if (!thread.isInterrupted()) { //check flag before starting long process
            //do a lot of long work that needs to be done in one pass
        }
        // do some stuff to setup for next step
        if (!thread.isInterrupted()) { //check flag before starting long process
            //do the next step of long work that needs to be done in one pass
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Surely this is not the case .. if it *was* true then there would *not* be the "standard" approach of keeping a separate volatile flag variable. `Thread.interrupt` is a *different* beast. With horns. (Note that it is used to force an "interrupt" of various *blocking* operations.)

Comment: @pst, actually this is the case. There are several instances in Oracle's JRE/JDK Java code in which the interrupt flag is simply checked and an exception thrown if it is set. Look at `ConditionObject.awaitNanos` in `AbstractQueuedSynchronizer`

Comment: @pst as far as the "standard" approach of keeping a separate volatile variable, I happily down vote any answer that dare suggest it.